# Integral-like concepts

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, integration

I am looking for interesting concepts (I guess you could say functionals from the function space $[a;b]\to\mathbb R$) that are like integrals in some respect.

The background is that I have proven a theorem containing an integral over a real-valued function on a compact interval. I then noticed that, in the proof, I only used the following properties:

- Integral of a constant function: $\int_a^b c\,\text{d}x = (b - a) c$ for any non-negative real number $c$ and $a\leq b$ .
- Integrability on subintervals: if $a\leq a'\leq b'\leq b$ and $f:[a;b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is integrable on $[a;b]$, it is also integrable on $[a';b']$ .
- Monotonicity: if $a\leq b$ and $f,g:[a;b]\to\mathbb{R}$ are integrable on $[a;b]$ and $f(x)\leq g(x)$ for all $x\in[a;b]$, then $\int_a^b f(x)\,\text{d}x \leq \int_a^b g(x)\,\text{d}x$ .
- Splitting an integral: if $a \leq b \leq c$ and $f:[a;c]\to\mathbb{R}$ is integrable on $[a;c]$, then $\int_a^c f(x)\,\text{d}x = \int_a^b f(x)\,\text{d}x + \int_b^c f(x)\,\text{d}x$ .

Now, I think that any reasonable concept of integration (Riemann, Lebesgue, Kurzweil–Henstock, …) should fulfil these four properties. But the interesting question is: are there any concepts other than integration (i.e. things that are not merely a generalisation of the Riemann integral) that fulfil these properties? If yes, I could generalise my theorem to this wider class of concepts.

The kinds of things I considered are something like 
$$\text{‘given}\ f\ \text{and}\ [a;b]\text{,}\ \text{return}\ (b-a)\cdot \sup\limits_{x\in[a;b]} f(x)\text{’}$$
where any continuous function is considered integrable. However, this violates the ‘splitting’ property.

Are there any interesting ways -- other than integration -- to turn a function $f$ on a compact interval $[a;b]$ into a single real number in a way that fulfils the above four properties?

Comment: http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~tl/glasgowpssl/banach.pdf might be relevant.

Comment: But not linearity? $\int_a^b (f(x)+g(x))dx = \int_a^b f(x)dx + \int_a^b g(x) dx$ ... if you add that then it will be the Riemann integral (or an extension).

Comment: No, I don't need linearity.

Comment: It looks to me like the "constant function" and "splitting" properties imply that step functions get assigned their Riemann integral.  Then monotonicity should imply that the same is true for continuous functions.  So unless I have missed some details (very possible), I think you may actually just recover the Riemann integral.

Comment: Oh yes indeed, I think you're right. It probably even holds for all Lebesgue-integrable functions then. Perhaps even Kurzweil–Henstock. I will try to prove this formally tomorrow.

Comment: Why should the characteristic function of the rationals be assigned its Lebesgue measure?

Comment: Yes, I thought about it some more yesterday and it seems that the reasoning can only be applied to functions with finitely many jump discontinuities.